# How to copy a script file to remote machine in Powershell through java?

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, powershell, powershell-2.0, powershell-remoting

Is there any way that we could copy our script files from local machine to remote machine in Powershell through Java?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: It is certainly possible but why not do this in Java proper? What protocol do you use to copy files which requires you to use PowerShell?

Comment: Actually, I am writing a script engine in java which has to copy scripts through powershell and execute on remote machine. @fge

Comment: A script engine on top of PoSh? *confused*